# Error: A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same

Tags: matlab

As I understand the `ber` matrix is not matching with `err`. Need help to overcome the error in the following code:

```
for snr= 1:50
err=0; 
ber = err;
No= 1/10^(snr/10);
    for i= 1: 10^6;
        x= sign (randn(2,1));
        h= randn (1,2) * sqrt(1/2) + sqrt (1/2)* 1j* randn(1,2);
        w= sqrt(No/2)* randn (1,2) + sqrt(No/2)*1j* randn(1,2);
        alamh=[ h(1) h(2); conj(h(2)) -conj(h(1))];
        y= alamh * x + transpose(w);
        h_pseudoinverse= inv(ctranspose(alamh)* alamh)\ ctranspose(alamh);
        r= x + h_pseudoinverse * transpose (w);
        est_x= sign(real(r));
        err= (est_x~=x)+err; 
    end        
ber(snr)= err/10^6;
end

semilogy (1:50, ber,'-O')
```

Error:

> Error: A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you want `ber` to be? after the inner loop runs `err` is a 2x1 matrix. If you want to store all the elements of `err` then you can for example (1) add a line `ber=NaN(2, 50);` before your code, (2) delete the line `ber = err;`, and (3) change the `ber(snr)...` line to `ber(:, snr) = err/10^6;`.

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem. Thanks.

Comment: If that solved the problem then accept the answer by @verbatross.

Answer (score 0):

After the inner loop runs, `err` is a 2x1 matrix. If you want to store each iteration of `err` in `ber` then you can, for example:

(1) add the line `ber = NaN(2, 50);` before your code,

(2) delete the line `ber = err;`, and

(3) change the line `ber(snr)...` to `ber(:, snr) = err/10^6;`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the third line 'ber = err', because in each loop you are defining err = 0 and then you are assigning ber = err which will make ber = 0. Moreover in line number 14, since 'est_x ~= x' gives you a column vector with 2 elements, you can add them up to get an estimate of the total number of bits in error. Here is the edited code:

```
            for snr= 1:50
            err=0; 
            % ber = err;
            No= 1/10^(snr/10);
                for i= 1: 10^6
                    x= sign (randn(2,1));
                    h= randn (1,2) * sqrt(1/2) + sqrt (1/2)* 1j* randn(1,2);
                    w= sqrt(No/2)* randn (1,2) + sqrt(No/2)*1j* randn(1,2);
                    alamh=[ h(1) h(2); conj(h(2)) -conj(h(1))];
                    y= alamh * x + transpose(w);
                    h_pseudoinverse= inv(ctranspose(alamh)* alamh)\ ctranspose(alamh);
                    r= x + h_pseudoinverse * transpose (w);
                    est_x= sign(real(r));
                    err= sum((est_x~=x))+err;
                end        
            ber(snr)= err/10^6;
            end

            semilogy (1:50, ber,'-O')
```